# Interquartile range for categorical data

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data, median, iqr

I have been asked to report the descriptive statistics of my results in terms of IQR and median for my categorical variables but I do not know how I can do that! I know the logic but in continuous data.

Can anyone explain how to calculate that on categorical variables? And how to do it in R?

Comment: Reporting the interquartile range for categorical variables makes little sense.  Consider, for example, a dataset that contains records for 50 males and 50 females.  What would a sensible (and informative) IQR for sex look like?

Comment: @Limey so it should be the 50% of the middle part of data? So 25% male and 25% female?...But the problem for one of the variables I have 52 categories containing from 1 to 2000 patients in each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to calculate median and IQR for variables grouped by a categorical variable. In base R, you can use aggregate for this. You can also look up tidyverse, which has the handy `group_by` and `summarize` functions.

```
df <- data.frame(
  c("m", "f", "m", "x"),
  c(20, 21, 64, 42),
  c(191, 180, 176, 177)
)
names(df) <- c("gender", "age", "length")
aggregate(length ~ gender, df, IQR)
aggregate(length ~ gender, df, median)
```

This has the output

```
aggregate(length ~ gender, df, IQR)
  gender length
1      f    0.0
2      m    7.5
3      x    0.0

aggregate(length ~ gender, df, median)
  gender length
  gender length
1      f  180.0
2      m  183.5
3      x  177.0
```